# copy symlink on macos using copyfile

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am using `copyfile(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath, nullptr, COPYFILE_CLONE)` on macOS to copy symlinks (see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/copyfile.3.html). I need to preserve the symlink and all its metadata. It works very well for file symlinks - it copies the symlink and the result is a symlink. But it does not work for directory symlinks (symlinks pointing to a directory). It is copied but the result is not preserved as symlink, it is a directory. I tried to add flag `COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW` but result is still the same. What am I doing wrong? Of is there any other way to copy symlinks pointing to directories with all their metadata?

Comment: Tried a sample on macOS 10.15 and your use case seems to work. `COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW` seems redundant anyway as `COPYFILE_CLONE` already cover `COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW_SRC`. Which version of macOS are you on?

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: So I found the problem. It was the trailing slash in paths. I deserve the minus points.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason for this error is simple: the path string ended with slash. My program treated the symlink to folder as a folder and included the trailing slash. Subsequently the link was copied as folder and not as link.

```
copyfile("/Users/vlad/link_to_dir/", "/Users/vlad/copy_of_link_to_dir/", nullptr, COPYFILE_CLONE);
```

simply copies the link as folder. The correct version which copies the symlink as a symlink is:

```
copyfile("/Users/vlad/link_to_dir", "/Users/vlad/copy_of_link_to_dir", nullptr, COPYFILE_CLONE);
```